# Copy a std::u8string into a c-style string of utf8 characters

Tags: c++, utf-8, c-strings, c++20, char8-t

Copying a string with no encodage into a c-string is quite easy:

```
auto to_c_str(std::string const& str) -> char* {
    auto dest = new char[str.size() + 1];
    return strcpy(dest, str.c_str());
}
```

But how can I do that with a `std::u8string`? Is there a STL algorithm that can help with that?

I tried this:

```
auto to_c_str(std::u8string const& str) -> char8_t* {
    auto dest = new char8_t[str.size() + 1];
    return std::strcpy(dest, str.c_str());
}
```

But of course, `std::strcpy` is not overloaded for utf8 strings.

Comment: The way UTF-8 is defined, I don't see any problem with what you have. Might as well just use `memcpy` for performance. Or am I missing the point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addtion to using `std::memcpy`, you may use `std::u8string::copy` and `std::copy`.

```
auto to_c_str(std::u8string const& str) -> char8_t* {
    auto dest = new char8_t[str.size() + 1];
    str.copy(dest, str.size(), 0);
    dest[str.size()] = u8'\0';
    return dest;
}

auto to_c_str(std::u8string const& str) -> char8_t* {
    auto dest = new char8_t[str.size() + 1];
    std::copy(str.begin(), str.end(), dest);
    dest[str.size()] = u8'\0';
    return dest;
}
```

Comment: Or `std::char_traits<char8_t>::copy` just to annoy ;)

Comment: @DeiDei I presume `std::u8string::copy` will use what char traits implements?

Comment: @DeiDei, who kew there were so many ways to copy  a sequence of characters!

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot Most probably, and in the end you'll end up with a `memcpy` somewhere.

Comment: Would the null terminator be `u8'\0'`?

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot, I like that suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

`strcpy` isn't needed since you already know the length of what you'd like to copy, so use `memcpy`:

```
char8_t* to_c_str(std::u8string const& str) {
    auto dest = new char8_t[str.size() + 1];
    return static_cast<char8_t*>(std::memcpy(dest, str.data(), str.size()+1));
}
```

or `std::copy`:

```
char8_t* to_c_str(std::u8string const& str) {
    auto dest = new char8_t[str.size() + 1];
    std::copy(str.data(), str.data() + str.size() + 1, dest);
    return dest;
}
```

Since the `u8string`'s own `copy()` method can't be used to include the null-terminator directly, I'd not use it when copying to a raw `char8_t*`.

Comment: I never had to deal with a lot of c-style strings. This clears things up, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me like it would be easier to simply leverage the built-in copying and provide `.data()` to the C code:

```
std::u8string orig = u8"abc";
auto copy = orig;
c_api(copy.data(), copy.size());
```

By doing this, you let the copied string manage its own lifetime and have the size on equal footing with the data. This works uniformly for any char type of `std::basic_string`. As an added bonus, it also works for `std::vector`.